# How to set size relative to monitor size within Scene Builder

Tags: javafx, set, size, monitor, scenebuilder

I wonder how I can set a size relative to the monitor being used inside Scene Builder? Is it possible?

Comment: There is probably no way to do this in SceneBuilder. FXML's most parent node is a root node(pane, hbox, etc), but you need to have access to Stage to resize it according to monitor size. I am just guessing here from my experience.

Comment: if auto computed size is used - does that mean a scene will be of different sizes depending on the monitor? And how do developers set the sizes they want specifically for each type of monitor? Is that a drawback of using Scenebuilder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426912/how-to-make-window-fullscreen-maximized-in-scene-builder

Comment: Thats why it is called SCENE builder I guess...